How to get gps coordinates, display them on the screen and send them to mysql database with flutter?
So bare with me as I am completely new to using flutter.
I have accomplished so far with my code the following:

User Login
Sending User To Home.dart passing username so I can display thier data from database.
Mysql / Php connection sending and receiving data to database.
Checking and Asking for permission for GPS Device Access.
Getting GPS Co-ordinates but only printing them to the debug terminal.
*Added^  Push to Text GPS coordinates.
This is where I need help / assistance / guidance.

The only thing left since I have gotten the gps data and null fixed and working is to get the username passed in and recognized.
Full Code Below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
String username;
HomePage({super.key, required this.username});
    


 
 
  @override
 _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
   

}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  
  
  Position? _currentPosition; 

  void _getUserPosition() async {
    await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    
    Position userLocation = await Geolocator
      .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best, forceAndroidLocationManager: true);

    setState(() {
      _currentPosition = userLocation;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserPosition();
  }
  
  
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Location"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            if (_currentPosition != null)
            Text(
"Your Position is:  LAT: ${_currentPosition?.latitude}, LNG: ${_currentPosition?.longitude}"
          ),
            
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Get location"),
              onPressed: () {
                _getUserPosition();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Before I added the code for createState the username was being passed in and recognized.  Now when I try to add $username to the Text to say $username your location is ...............  It keeps telling me undefined.
So the help that I need is how to get the string username recognized.  It worked before the createState was added and not it doesn't and I don't know enough about flutter to know why.

probally there is error while check perssiion or request permission.  i highly recommend  to use example code here https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#example

So I did even more reading and I found my solution or an adaptable solution.
Changed HomePage({super.key, required this.username});
To This:   HomePage({required this.username});
Changed @override _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
To This:  @override State<StatefulWidget> createState(){ return _HomePageState(username); }
Then finally added:  String username; _HomePageState(this.username);
Under This:  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
Now onto the next part of this flutter project and that is to send the gps to the database and then change the elevated button to Start and add another one called stop and put it all in a timer that can be started and then stopped.
Just as I was starting to get a handle on Android, now I have to learn a whole new development tool.  The hardest part for me is designing, I am by no means a full stack developer.  I write the code to make the design work, but I don't design which is what is making flutter a challenge for me because you have to know both.  Hope this helps someone out there with similar issues.
